# Linux serial port communication using java and RXTX lib

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, serial-communication, rxtx

I create a program to communicate with serial ports in linux, I used Netbeans IDE for this , and I added rxtx jar file and its driver.

It is working fine when I run it from Netbeans but it gives an error when I try to run it from outside of Netbeans.

Error is:

> driver are not linked while loading drivers.

I put rxtx.jar in ext folder of jre AND driver are in the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is pointing to a folder in which you have your RxTx native libraries. You can tell java to use concrete folder as a library folder by adding `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/my/dll` parameter to the `java` invocation from command line.

Comment: java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+122)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+122, mixed mode)

Comment: Netbeans configuration is:- Java: 1.8.0_91; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b14
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_91-b14
System: Linux version 4.4.0-21-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_IN (nb)

Comment: -Djava.library.path="/home/gurjeet/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/"